# Use same resource(such as created socket) in more than two php file

Tags: php, sockets, resources

I wrote a very basic socket server in php(socketsever.php). I use nohup to let it run in background. 
I want to use the socket resource created in socketserver.php in other pages. So when someone view some page, Server will send something through socket.
I can't find the way to use socket resource in socketserver in other pages.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is SO_REUSEADDR.  This will allow multiple connections to the port that the php script is listening on.  You can do this by simply setting this socket option after doing socket_create.

example from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-option.php)

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

if (!is_resource($socket)) {
    echo 'Unable to create socket: '. socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . PHP_EOL;
}

if (!socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {
    echo 'Unable to set option on socket: '. socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . PHP_EOL;
}

if (!socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 1223)) {
    echo 'Unable to bind socket: '. socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . PHP_EOL;
}

$rval = socket_get_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR);

if ($rval === false) {
    echo 'Unable to get socket option: '. socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . PHP_EOL;
} else if ($rval !== 0) {
    echo 'SO_REUSEADDR is set on socket !' . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```